# Standalone jQuery spellchecker Exists?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Does standalone jQuery spellchecker exists? i.e, without using ajax/webservices/assembly.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for a client side spellchecking library, I am using typo.js in my mvc project:

http://www.chrisfinke.com/2011/03/31/announcing-typo-js-client-side-javascript-spellchecking/

https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js

Comment: How to use it? can you help me out with an example as it is returning the array of possible suggestions for a word but i am not sure how to apply this on a text area.
Do I need to write script manually to replace the mis-spelled text?

Comment: I am using it with CodeMirror, it's a more complicated text editor than a textarea, but typo doesn't do the replace it self, it can tell you if a word is misspelled `dictionary.check("mispelled")` and it can give you the suggestions `dictionary.suggest("mispeling")` but you have to take it from there!

Comment: so I need to check for every word?
For eg, if my sentence holds 50 word than when and where i should check for misspelled word? and do i have to highlight the incorrect spelled word manually?

Comment: yes you will need to check every word